# Как передать картинку через props? vue.js

Tags: vue.js

В дочернем компоненте header-app

```
<template>
        <img :src='img'>
</template>
<script>
export default {
      props: ['img']
}
</script>
```

Пытаюсь вывести картинку, но не работает

```
<template>
<header-app img="assets/logo.png" ></header-app>
</template>
```

что я делаю не так?

в дом значение img попадает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но сама картинка не отображается

Comment: `</template` - скобку не забыл?

Comment: Если значение попадает, а фото не отображается - то значит ошибка в передаваемом значении. Проверьте, действительно ли есть изображение по этому адресу

Comment: @Plikard проверил уже, дело явно не в путях

Comment: В данном случе дело точно в путях. Для многостраничного приложения попробуй передать АБСОЛЮТНЫЙ путь

Answer (score 0):

Во vue.js по default чтобы перейти в папочку src используют сочетание знаков './' либо же alias '@'. В твоем случае правильнее было написать "./assets/logo.png". Скажу заранее, если ты в данные момент находишься в папке (например: создал дочерний элемент и запихнул его в папку, а теперь пытаешься достучаться до картинки в другой папке) то с начало тебе необходимо из нее выйти, для этого используют сочетание знаков '../' (пример: "../assets/logo.png")